# Performance and Scaling of RoR in a Tumblr clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ember.js, mean-stack

Is it a good idea to build an RoR app which is similar to tumblr, or should I use a newer stack such as MEAN/MEEN? And what are the issues I might run into in the long run?

The reason I ask is because I read a lot about the scaling issues of rails. Could you be specific in what issues one might have with RoR in this particular case.

Since

Comment: is the application live? What the highest load your app has faced during its peak.

Comment: Are you planning on getting as big as Twitter in a hurry? If not, Rails is likely to scale well enough to meet your needs.

Comment: can you share what all issues you see if you use RoR and how big is ur app... without knowing this, all answers would be vauge

Comment: The site is not live. I have just wire framed it and started working on it using RoR. I know for a fact that I will not scale to the levels of twitter, or even Tumbler for that matter. I also know I need to implement Ember or Angular for most of the client side. I should have framed the question in a better way. Is it better to use ROR with ember/angular for something like tumblr/wordpress.com, or use Mean/Meen? Which would give me better performance and scalability in the long run.